# Neo4j db.schema() via API

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Is it possible to send the cypher command

```
call db.schema()
```

via the neo4j rest api?

Answer (score 1):

Got it:

```
POST | http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit 
{"statements":[{
  "statement":"call db.schema()",
  "resultDataContents":["graph"]}]}
```